# Why does this Grid/TextBlock not get created?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm adding a UI to some code I wrote for a messenger, some while ago. It seems to be going OK, apart from when I try to display new messages from a different thread.

The program flows thusly:

1. The `MainWindow` gets created and instantiated. The constructor for `MainWindow`:

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       _messageContainer = (StackPanel)FindName("Messages");
       _messageStatus = (StatusBarItem)FindName("MessageStatus");
       _messageCountElement = (StatusBarItem)FindName("MessageCount");
       _messageBox = (TextBox)FindName("MessageToSend");
       _sendButton = (Button)FindName("SendMessage");

       _ipAddress = GetIPAddress();
       try
       {
           Client.Initialize(_ipAddress, this);
           _sendButton.IsEnabled = true;
           _messageBox.IsEnabled = true;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           DisplayMessage("Could not connect to " + _ipAddress.ToString() + ". The error given was '" + e.Message + "'.", "Server", Colors.Red);
       }
   }
   ```
2. The sending client (`Client` class) is initialized using `Client.Initialize` from the `MainWindow` constructor. `Client.Initialize`:

   ```
   public static void Initialize(IPEndPoint endPoint, MainWindow window)
   {
       windowInstance = window;
       client = new TcpClient();
       client.ReceiveTimeout = 500;
       listenerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Receiver.Start));
       listenerThread.Start((object)new StartupData(endPoint, windowInstance));
       client.Connect(endPoint);
   }
   ```
3. The listener thread is started from `Client.Initialize`. The listener thread's `Start` method is long and complicated, but works fine. It boils down to calling another method, `ProcessMessage` to process what it receives. `ProcessMessage`:

   ```
   public static void ProcessMessage(string response)
   {
       response = response.Trim();

       MessageBox.Show(response);

       if (response.StartsWith("[Message]"))
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Message");
           response = response.Substring(9);

           int openIndex = response.IndexOf("<");
           int closeIndex = response.IndexOf(">");

           if (openIndex < 0 || closeIndex < 0 || closeIndex < openIndex)
           {
               throw new FormatException("Could not find ID tag in message");
           }

           int diff = closeIndex - openIndex;
           int id = Int32.Parse(response.Substring(openIndex + 1, diff - 1));
           if (id != Client.GetClientId())
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Them");
               string message = response.Substring(closeIndex + 1);
               window.DisplayMessage(message, "Them", Colors.Yellow);
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("You");
               string message = response.Substring(closeIndex + 1);
               window.DisplayMessage(message, "You", Colors.Blue);
           }
       }
       else if (response.Length == 5 && response.StartsWith("[") && response.EndsWith("]"))
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Response code");
           Client.HandleResponse(ResponseCodes.GetResponse(response));
       }
       else
       {
           try
           {
               Int32.Parse(response);
               MessageBox.Show("ID");
               Client.SetClientId(Int32.Parse(response));
               return;
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
               window.DisplayMessage(response, "Server", Colors.Red);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. The `DisplayMessage` method is called. `DisplayMessage`:

   ```
   public void DisplayMessage(string message, string name, Color nameColor)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Called");

       UpdateMessageStatus(ProcessingStatus.Processing);

       Grid fullMessage = new Grid();
       fullMessage.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(50.00) });
       fullMessage.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(600.00) });

       Label nameLabel = new Label
       {
           Content = string.Format("[{0}]", name),
           Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(nameColor)
       };
       Grid.SetColumn(nameLabel, 0);

       TextBlock textLabel = new TextBlock
       {
           Text = message,
           TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
           Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5)
       };
       Grid.SetColumn(textLabel, 1);

       fullMessage.Children.Add(nameLabel);
       fullMessage.Children.Add(textLabel);

       UpdateMessageStatus(ProcessingStatus.Displaying);
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
       {
           _messageContainer.Children.Add(fullMessage);
       }));        

       _messageCount += 1;
       UpdateMessageCount();
       UpdateMessageStatus(ProcessingStatus.Ready);
   }
   ```

Here is the problem. When I call `window.DisplayMessage` from the listener thread, *literally nothing* happens. Not even an exception - but importantly, the message Grid doesn't get created.

What's up with this? I added `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` on the advice of another SO question to make sure the thread ownership wasn't a problem, though the same thing happened before this.

(note: all the `MessageBox`es are just for debugging. Interestingly, the `MessageBox` at the top of `DisplayMessage` *does* show when called from the listener thread.)

Comment: Are you  sure you're actually on the UI thread with that call to BeginInvoke? Try `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and see if that yields different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do suspect this is an issue of cross-thread UI element invokation. Since you are creating your new UI element (`fullMessage` and its children) on a different thread.

If your `window` instance is a WPF `UserControl` or a WPF [`Window`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can use it's synchronization context to perform the cross-thread marshaling.

- Capture its synchronization context in your `MainWindow` constructor

  ```
  _syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  ```
- Add a method that uses the captured context, to marshal to the correct dispatcher.

  ```
  public void InvokeDisplayMessage(string message, string name, Color nameColor)
  {
      // In the already started spirit of message box debugging ;-)
      MessageBox.Show("InvokeDisplayMessage Called");
      this._syncContext.Post(
          new SendOrPostCallback(x => DisplayMessage(message, name, nameColor)), 
          null);
  }
  ```
- And finally change all of the `window.DisplayMessage` calls in your `ProcessMessage` to 
  `window.InvokeDisplayMessage`.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, A better way is possible, I will update my answer to reflect that.